# What problem does the Kleisli arrows solve in fp-ts?

Tags: fp-ts

I'm learning functional programming by using fp-ts lib and noticed that some functions end with `K`, like:

- `chainTaskEitherK`
- `chainEitherK`
- `fromTaskK`

Also I read the explanation of [What a `K` suffix means](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/code-conventions.html#what-a-k-suffix-means-eg-fromeitherk-or-chaineitherk) in fp-ts documentation, but unfortunately I can't say that one example gives me a solid idea of how to use it on the battlefield.

I would like to know exactly what problem they solve and what the code would look like without them (to see the benefit).

Please, consider that I'm a newbie in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

First, (going off of the example in the link you shared). I think a Kleisli arrow is just a name for a type that looks like:

```js
<A>(value: A) => F<A>
```

where `F` is some Functor value. They call it a constructor in the doc you linked which might be more precise? My understanding is that it's just a function that takes some non-Functor value (a `string` in the parse example) and puts it into some Functor.

These helpers you've listed are there for when you already have a Kleisli arrow and you want to use it with some other Functor values. In the example they have

```js
declare function parse(s: string): Either<Error, number>;
```

and they have an `IOEither` value that would probably come from user input. They want to combine the two, basically run `parse` on the input if it's a `Right` and end up with a function using `parse` with the signature:

```js
declare function parseForIO(s: string): IOEither<Error, number>;
```

This is so the return type can be compatible with our input type (so we can use `chain` on the `IOEither` to compose our larger function).

`fromEitherK` is therefore, wrapping the base `parse` function in some logic to naturally transform the resulting regular `Either` into an `IOEither`. The `chainEitherK` does that and a `chain` to save some of the boilerplate.

Basically, it's solving a compatibility issue when the return value from your Kleisli arrows doesn't match the value you need when `chaining` things together.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @Souperman explanation I want to share my investigation on this topic

Let's take [already known example](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/code-conventions#what-a-k-suffix-means-eg-fromeitherk-or-chaineitherk) from the `fp-ts` documentation.

We have an `input` variable of type `IOEtiher`

```js
const input: IE.IOEither<Error, string> = IE.right('foo')
```

and function, which take a plain `string` and returns `E.Either`

```js
function parse(s: string): E.Either<Error, number> {
  // implentation
}
```

If we want to make this code works together in a fp-ts style, we need to introduce a `pipe`. `pipe` is a function which passes our data through the functions listed inside the pipe.

So, instead of doing this (imperative style)

```js
const input: IE.IOEither<Error, string> = IE.right('foo')

const value = input()

let result: E.Either<Error, number>

if (value._tag === 'Right') {
  result = parse(value.right) // where value.right is our 'foo'
}
```

We can do this

```js
pipe(
 input,
 IE.chain(inputValue => parse(inputValue))
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <- Error is shown
)
```

Error message

```
Type 'Either<Error, number>' is not assignable to type 'IOEither<Error, unknown>'.
```

Unfortunately, fp-ts cannot implicitly jump between types (e.g. from `IOEither` to `Either`) . In our example, we started with `input` variable which has `IOEither` (`IE` shortened) type and continue with a `IE.chain` method which tries to return `Either` value.

To make it work we can introduce a function which helps us to convert this types.

```js
pipe(
 input,
 IE.chain(inputValue => IE.fromEitherK(parse)(inputValue))
)
```

Now our `chain` function explicitly know that `parse` function was converted from `Either` type to `IOEither` by using `fromEitherK`.

At this moment we can see that `fromEitherK` is a helper function that expects a `Kleisli` function in its arguments and return the new function with a new return type.

To make it more clear, we needn't to use a `K` suffix if, for example, our `parse` was a value (instead of function).

The code would look like

```js
pipe(
 input,
 IE.chain(inputValue => IE.fromEither(parsed)) // I know this is useless code, but it shows its purpose
)
```

Returning back to our example. We can improve the code to make it more readable

Instead of this

```js
pipe(
 input,
 IE.chain(inputValue => IE.fromEitherK(parse)(inputValue))
)
```

We can do this

```js
pipe(
 input,
 IE.chain(IE.fromEitherK(parse))
)
```

And even more

```js
pipe(
 input,
 IE.chainEitherK(parse)
)
```

Summary

As far I understand, a Kleisli arrows are the functions which take an argument and return a result wrapped in a container (like `parse` function).